# Kafka Consumer InvalidOperationException

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, kafkaflow

I have a Kafka consumer giving the exception below. What is this indicating and how can it be resolved? It seems like it is trying to consume from a queue that has nothing on it, but I'm not sure how that is happening.

[image]

I don't know if it is related but I'm also seeing items not being consumed from a topic. I have multiple topics being consumed so is there a way to determine which topic is receiving the exception.

Comment: Can you share the KafkaFlow version you are using? There was an issue related to this that was solved in a recent KafkaFlow version., maybe updating can fix the issue.

Comment: I'm currently using 2.2.4 of the KafkaFlow nuget packages.

Comment: Can you please update to the latest version and check if the issue is fixed?

Comment: I updated and have not seen the message since but I also change the way we store offsets at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is not set the offset for your consumer group. Then you need to configure strategy, from what place you want to start to read. See this section in KafkaFlow documentation.

https://farfetch.github.io/kafkaflow/docs/guides/consumers/add-consumers#offset-strategy